# panda, filter DataFrame and sum repeat Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

welcome everybody.

i have dataFrame Like this,
I want to calculate the value of the row repeated with the next row, and delete the previous row.

For values calculated from Date, I want to put them in another column.

`The recurring values X are summed without the price, In the duplicate values in A. Then delete the previous values X.`

`As for the Date, it increases by 30 minutes, there is no value smaller than the previous value, in my DataFrame`

`I think that if the Date was converted to timestamp, the subtraction would be easier. The result may be 30minut or 60minut or 90minut Or whatever the result is in minutes`

`For example, calculate time like this:`

```
from datetime import datetime

//convert timestamps to datetime object
start_ts_ = datetime.fromtimestamp(1652426243.907874)
end_ts = datetime.fromtimestamp(1652436243.907874)

//Difference between two timestamps in seconds
delta = end_ts - start_ts_
print(f'{delta.total_seconds() / 60.0}' )
```

Output: 166minut

```
                Date   price  client  Count    test
  0    2023-09-28 10:30    5       5       3        0
  1    2023-09-28 11:00    7       7       9        L
------------------------------------------------------
X 2    2023-09-28 11:30    3       1       10       GG
------------------------------------------------------
A 3    2023-09-28 12:00    4       3       15       GG
------------------------------------------------------
  4    2023-09-28 12:30    2       8       1        L
------------------------------------------------------
X 5    2023-09-28 13:00    7       4       8        GG
X 6    2023-09-28 13:30    5       6       9        GG
X 7    2023-09-28 14:00    7       4       8        GG
X 8    2023-09-28 14:30    5       6       9        GG
X 9    2023-09-28 15:00    7       4       8        GG
------------------------------------------------------
A 10   2023-09-28 13:30    5       6       9        GG
------------------------------------------------------
X 11   2023-09-28 16:00    1       3       12       L
X 12   2023-09-28 14:30    6       1       11       L
------------------------------------------------------
A 13   2023-09-28 16:00    1       3       12       L
  14   2023-09-28 16:30    5       6       9        GG
```

The result is like this:

```
                Date   price  client  Count    test   time
0   2023-09-28 10:30    5       5       3        0      30minut
1   2023-09-28 11:00    7       7       9        L      30minut
3   2023-09-28 12:00    4       4       25       GG     1H
4   2023-09-28 13:30    2       8       1        L      30minut
6   2023-09-28 14:30    5       10      17       GG     1H
8   2023-09-28 15:30    6       4       23       L      1H
```

The values that are calculated in the columns are: client & Count.

I know this can be complicated.
Please Help
Thank you

Comment: Please define the difference between 30minut and 1H, how do you decide which lines should be merged with new values?

Comment: Can you please breadk down the computation of "time"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For example
2023-09-28 11:30 minus 2023-09-28 12:00
Equals 1 hour
Each row contains 30 minutes.
Calculating 30 minutes in the first row and 30 minutes in the second row, equals 1 hour

Comment: @Ben please [edit] the question with those details, comments are not made for code/data. And please explain all the rows because given this logic I'd compute different numbers. Also how do you handle `12:00` that comes after `13:30`?

Comment: thank you mozway i edit the question, please reply.

Comment: @Ben sorry but the logic is still unclear, why is the `L` in index `4` having `13:30` and not `12:30`? Why don't you sum all values (e.g. row 3, why 4/4/25)? Why is the last GG group missing? etc. there are many unknowns

Comment: I modified the code and now it works fine, thank you very much.
agg = {'Date': 'last', 'price': 'last', 'client': 'sum', 'Count': 'sum', 'test': 'last', 'time': 'sum' }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you want to group the consecutive "test" after computing the diff:

```
# ensure datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# group successive values
group = df['test'].ne(df['test'].shift()).cumsum()

# define aggregations
agg = {'Date': 'first', 'price': 'sum', 'client': 'sum', 'Count': 'sum', 'test': 'first', 'time': 'sum'}

# compute diff, aggregate consecutive values
out = df.assign(time=df['Date'].diff()).groupby(group).agg(agg)
```

Output:

```
                    Date  price  client  Count test            time
test                                                               
1    2023-09-28 10:30:00      5       5      3    0 0 days 00:00:00
2    2023-09-28 11:00:00      7       7      9    L 0 days 00:30:00
3    2023-09-28 11:30:00      7       4     25   GG 0 days 01:00:00
4    2023-09-28 13:30:00      2       8      1    L 0 days 01:30:00
5    2023-09-28 12:00:00     12      10     17   GG 0 days 01:00:00
6    2023-09-28 15:00:00      7       4     23    L 0 days 01:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
The code is great and clean.
But the data of the last row of duplicate values is deleted, and I want the opposite.
What I want is to delete (index 2 & not 3) and (index 5 & not 6) and  and (index 7 & not 8)

Comment: @Ben whey don't you edit your question with the requested details? Explain for each row in the output how exactly the input values are used. Also double check that the output is correct..